# How do I list redirects to current node in a view

Tags: views, redirection

In [views 7.x-3.7](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.7):

I'm using Contextual Filters to create a view tab for each node displaying metadata about that node, e.g., content type, last edited date, last edited by. I'd like to add any redirects (using the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module) to that display.

That is, I have an existing view `/node/%/about-this-node` such that
if I have node `[domain]/node/12345`
with a display tab `[domain]/node/12345/about-this-node` (created from my view)

And `[domain]/myshortcut` redirects to `[domain]/node/12345`

How do I add a views field to `[domain]/node/12345/about-this-node` that lists myshortcut?

I would have expected an entity reference field that would allow me to accomplish this, but I can't seem to find any such field where this information would be available.